Using singular value decomposition to find unknown matrices
I want to know whether is it possible to solve this problem using SVD or not? Here is the problem:
I want to find unknown matrices B and C so that:
$$((Y+jC)^{-1}+jB)^{-1}=sI+jA$$
$j$ is the unit of imaginary,
$Y$ is a known complex matrix that is symmetric, $A$ can be any arbitrary Hermitian matrix, $s$ is a known real scalar, $I$ is the identity matrix, $B$ and $C$ are diagonal matrices with real elements. All matrices are 2 by 2.
This problem has infinite number of solutions, I want to know that how many degrees of freedom are there for $B$ and $C$?
Thanks.

Let $X=(sI+jA)^{-1}$. The equation can be rewritten as $(X-jB)(Y+jC) = I_2$ or $XY + jXC - jBY + BC = I_2$. Hence there are four equations in four unknowns, with two of them linear and the other two quadratic. Usually, it is possible to eliminate variables one by one.
